# Troubleshooting using a function in a DataWindow computed field PB 6.5

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I've written a function that accepts a string, looks up a value, and replies a string - and for some reason, I can't use it in our DataWindow that's a printed report. I've run the debugger and I see that it's walking through my function and is returning a string. I've done some searching that it's possible to use functions, but I'm stuck - we don't typically work on this application as it's  a bit "legacy" in the organization, so this might be something easy that I'm overlooking.

My computed field is `"Suggested case: " + string(f_get_case_size(SKU))` and I'm seeing it go through the function - but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Given that the function is global, i can be called from a computed field or a DW expression. Are you sure that the function returns something for the parameter at the line where your computed field is? What do you get instead of the expected result?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't use it in our DataWindow..."?  are you receiving an error?  If the function returns a string why are you using the "string" method in the computed field?

Comment: Are you sure f_get_case_size is returning a value and not null? A PowerBuilder string won't display if any part of it is null.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's response - unfortunately I think this issue might have been my inexperience with the program. I replaced all the function with the return string of "RESULTS!" and it showed up when I previewed the DataWindow - although anytime I had it use any of the calculations in the function the computed field didn't show up at all. In the end, I was debugging the function trying to find out which part was breaking when I checked the PDF output and saw my computed field. Preview wasn't evaluating for some reason - but everything works correctly when you put it to full speed.